# No matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1"

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, argocd

I am getting an error message indicating that the Kubernetes resource defined in the file "argocdingress.yaml" is of type "Ingress", but the version of the Kubernetes API being used (networking.k8s.io/v1) does not have a resource type called "Ingress".*

```
error: unable to recognize "argocdingress.yaml": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1"
```

```
[root@uat-master01 yaml]# kubectl apply -f argocdingress.yaml
```

```
error: unable to recognize "argocdingress.yaml": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1"
```

```
argocdingress.yaml
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1kind: Ingressmetadata:name: argocdingressnamespace: argocdannotations:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /spec:rules:
```

- ```
  host: argocd.fonepay.comhttp:paths:
  ```

  - ```
    path: /pathType: Prefixpath: /pathType: Prefixbackend:your textservice:name: argocd-serverport:name: http
    ```

```
[root@uat-master01 yaml]# kubectl get all -n argocd
```

```
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGEpod/argocd-redis-66b48966cb-v4vwg         1/1     Running   0          19hpod/argocd-repo-server-7d956f8689-bl5dr   1/1     Running   0          19hpod/argocd-server-598494dbc7-pd2g5        1/1     Running   0          19hpod/argocd-application-controller-0       1/1     Running   0          19hpod/argocd-dex-server-8b975c7cc-42b26     1/1     Running   0          19h
```

```
NAME                                              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGEservice/argocd-applicationset-controller          ClusterIP   10.43.157.126   <none>        7000/TCP,8080/TCP            19hservice/argocd-dex-server                         ClusterIP   10.43.120.182   <none>        5556/TCP,5557/TCP,5558/TCP   19hservice/argocd-metrics                            ClusterIP   10.43.202.235   <none>        8082/TCP                     19hservice/argocd-notifications-controller-metrics   ClusterIP   10.43.99.138    <none>        9001/TCP                     19hservice/argocd-redis                              ClusterIP   10.43.118.67    <none>        6379/TCP                     19hservice/argocd-repo-server                        ClusterIP   10.43.9.59      <none>        8081/TCP,8084/TCP            19hservice/argocd-server                             ClusterIP   10.43.251.211   <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP               19hservice/argocd-server-metrics                     ClusterIP   10.43.5.168     <none>        8083/TCP                     19h
```

```
NAME                                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGEdeployment.apps/argocd-redis         1/1     1            1           19hdeployment.apps/argocd-repo-server   1/1     1            1           19hdeployment.apps/argocd-server        1/1     1            1           19hdeployment.apps/argocd-dex-server    1/1     1            1           19h
```

```
NAME                                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGEreplicaset.apps/argocd-redis-66b48966cb         1         1         1       19hreplicaset.apps/argocd-repo-server-7d956f8689   1         1         1       19hreplicaset.apps/argocd-server-598494dbc7        1         1         1       19hreplicaset.apps/argocd-dex-server-8b975c7cc     1         1         1       19h
```

```
NAME                                             READY   AGEstatefulset.apps/argocd-application-controller   1/1     19h
```

```
nodeInfo:architecture: amd64bootID: 031dadd6-5586-453e-8add-ade7591791b7containerRuntimeVersion: containerd://1.3.3-k3s2kernelVersion: 3.10.0-1160.81.1.el7.x86_64kubeProxyVersion: v1.18.9+k3s1kubeletVersion: v1.18.9+k3s1machineID: 091bbe3a46464c0bac4082cd351b8db4operatingSystem: linuxosImage: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)systemUUID: CADD0442-7251-AE77-6375-D151A94CF9A7
```

```
Check by updating
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
```

Comment: Are you running kubernetes 1.19 or later? According to the docs Ingress is stable as of 1.19; i see some 1.18 references in your code blocks.

Comment: I am actually using v1.18.9+k3s1

Comment: So there you go. Ingress is still in beta in 1.18. You need to use api version `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` and review the deprecation docs to see if there were any structural differences between the later stable api and the beta. Or, you know, upgrade. K8s 1.22 just went out of support, you're so far behind it's kind of scary.

Comment: Now i am being encountered with validation issue;                                           
[root@uat-master01 yaml]# kubectl apply -f argocdingress.yaml
error: error validating "argocdingress.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown field "service" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1beta1.IngressBackend; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Comment: Like I said you need to find the deprecation/release/migration notes for 1.19 in the kubernetes documentation to figure out what changed between v1beta1 and v1.

Comment: It would be smarter and simpler to upgrade your kubernetes version because yours has been out of support for over a year.

Comment: Found the solution. service name and port should be defined like these < serviceName: argocd-server, servicePort: http >